# Using tqdm in Python scripts executed through Taskfile does not show a live progress bar

Tags: python, tqdm, taskfile

When using the [tqdm](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm) package for showing a progress bar in Python scripts, it does not display properly when the script is run through [Taskfile](https://taskfile.dev/). Using tqdm in a for loop should display a progress bar, but if the script is run through Taskfile, the completed progress bar is only displayed after the loop finished running.

It's a problem I had for a long time. I could not find anything online, so now that I solved it, I'm posting it here.

Answer (score 0):

There is a setting in *Taskfile* that improves the display of interactive scripts: *[Interactive CLI application](https://taskfile.dev/usage/#interactive-cli-application)*. Setting `interactive` to `true`  also solves the issue encountered with tqdm.

```
version: '3'

tasks:
  default:
    cmds:
      - python scriptWithTqdm.py
    interactive: true
```